# Maclaurin Series for $f(x)=x \sin2x$ - is there a quick way?

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=x \sin2x$

I need to find the first 3 non zero terms. Instead of working out multiple derivatives, is there a faster way of doing this? I've tried finding the derivatives and got to around the 6th derivative before I got overwhelmed by having to do the product rule.

Comment: If you know the series for $\sin{x}$ is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can multiply Maclaurin series and also change variables.

$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} +\frac{x^5}{120}+\ldots $$

Replace $x\mapsto 2x$,

$$\sin 2x = 2x - \frac{4x^3}{3} +\frac{4x^5}{15}+\ldots $$

Finally multiply by $x$,

$$x \sin 2x = 2x^2 - \frac{4x^4}{3} +\frac{4x^6}{15}+\ldots $$

Answer (score 1):

**Since** $$(e^x)'=e^x$$ it is very easy to obtain, for $x$ is near $0$:
$$
e^x= 1 +x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)
$$
then, recalling that  $\displaystyle \,\sin x = \frac{1}{2i} (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ you easily get
$$
\sin 2x = 2x-\frac{4x^3}{3}+\frac{4x^5}{15}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)
$$
and
$$
x\sin 2x = 2x^2-\frac{4x^4}{3}+\frac{4x^6}{15}+\mathcal{O}(x^7)
$$ as desired.

Comment: Even simpler, $\sin x=\Im e^{ix}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $x\sin (2x) = x\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{(2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$